# Drawing images with canvas is more efficient than let browser to render it?

Tags: html, canvas, rendering

It seems google images search is using canvas to draw images and original images are hidden from the beginning.

Have anyone tested that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that this is multi-faceted. First, it likely helps to spur image piracy from Google's site (eliminating some liability). Also, it enables lazy loading and lazy rendering for the images. Consider that a more apt placeholder can be drawn during the loading period while still maintaining layout.

Comment: Btw, why does lazy load is hiding images if they all have been loaded?
Hiding images that are outside screen saves memory or what?